# Replace a span tag with an anchor tag using a Python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an HTML string, and I want to replace `<span>` tags with `<a>` tags.

From this:

```html
<span>
    <span data-oe-model="demo.demo" data-oe-id="33" id="a">
        @Joseph Walters
    </span>
    hi
</span>
```

to this:

```html
<span>
    <a href="demo.demo/33" id="a">@Joseph Walters</a>
    hi
</span>
```

I want 3 groups using RegEx: `data-oe-model`, `data-oe-id`, and name `@Joseph Walters`.

**Note**: `data-oe-model` and `data-oe-id` need to combine into href.

Is this possible with a Python RegEx?

I have tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/wY6eI5/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
<span data-oe-model="([^"]*)"\s+data-oe-id="([^"]*)"\s+id="([^"]*)">(.*?)\</span>
```

And replace with the following:

```
<a href="\1\2" id="\3">\4</a>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wY6eI5/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values for data-oe-model & data-oe-id first. And then use re.sub

```
a="""<span><span data-oe-model="demo.demo" data-oe-id="33" id="a">@Joseph Walters</span> hi</span>"""
data_oe_model = re.findall(r'data-oe-model="(.*?)"', a)[0]
data_oe_id = re.findall(r'data-oe-id="(.*?)"', a)[0]
b = re.sub('span data-oe-model="(.*?)" data-oe-id="(.*?)"', 'a href='+data_oe_model+'/'+data_oe_id, a)

print  b

Output: <span><a href=demo.demo/33 id="a">@Joseph Walters</span> hi</span>
```

Note: Do some validations while getting the values by list indexing.